# MooTools: Element disposal

Tags: javascript, mootools

Let's say I have two elements on a page. One is a div, and the other is its child, an achor. Let's say that I've added an event to that anchor via `anchor.addEvent('click', ...)`. If I set the div's `.innerHTML = ''`, does the '`click`' event associated with the anchor get removed/disposed of/garbage collected?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have still reference to "anchor" DOM instance. If so, it will stay in memory until all references are removed.

Test example:

```
var parent = new Element('div');
var child = new Element('div', {
    events : {
        click : function() { 
            alert('child clicked'); 
        }
    }
});
child.innerHTML = 'child content';
parent.appendChild(child);
document.body.appendChild(parent);
parent.innerHTML = 'parent content';
document.body.appendChild(child);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MooTools API](http://mootools.net/docs/core): [`destroy()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:destroy) is a method that:

> Empties an Element of all its children, removes and garbages the Element. Useful to clear memory before the pageUnload.

I suspect that what happens to anchors removed when their parent elements are removed using `innerHTML = ''` is going to depend on the browser.

jQuery offers an [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method, I am guessing other libraries probably offer methods too. You can see a pretty good discussion of this topic in [**Removing an element from DOM**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479657/removing-an-element-from-dom).

Comment: I use destroy() in MooTools when I want to completely get rid of something.

Answer (score 0):

1. IMHO, you should use empty() instead of innerHTML = "".
2. The reference will remain like @nemisj said, but it will be "floating" and useless.
   I did some tests here: [test case](http://mootools.net/shell/3Ft8F/), maybe you'll find interesting.